# An unexpected error has occurred - There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: node.js, npm

Im facing with a problem below and I do not catch what the problem is.
below is the error message.

---

=== Deploying to 'ttss-6c3a2'...

i  deploying hosting 
i  hosting: preparing dist directory for upload...

Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 2 
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 deploy: `vue-cli-service build && firebase deploy`
npm ERR! Exit status 2 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR!     /Users/junp/.npm/_logs/2018-11-01T07_23_48_857Z-debug.log

---

and this is the complete log.

---

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deploy' ]
2 info using npm@5.3.0
3 info using node@v8.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeploy', 'deploy', 'postdeploy' ]
5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~predeploy: client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~deploy: client@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~deploy: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~deploy: PATH: /Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/Users/junp/Workspace/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin
9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~deploy: CWD: /Users/junp/Workspace
10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~deploy: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service build && firebase deploy' ]
11 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~deploy: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~deploy: Failed to exec deploy script
13 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 deploy: `vue-cli-service build && firebase deploy`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:289:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/junp/Workspace
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin/node" "/Users/junp/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin/npm" "run" "deploy"
18 verbose node v8.6.0
19 verbose npm  v5.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error client@0.1.0 deploy: `vue-cli-service build && firebase deploy`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 deploy script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Im not a programmer or this web-code built man but I need to solve this problem. please let me know what i have to do now...!

thanks!